# How can I append the incoming strings of a serial port to a text box?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, serial-port

I am a c# sharp beginner and my first project is a terminal application for the serial port. The incoming data are ascii characters and they come with 115 kbaud.

Now I want to bind each incoming line to a wpf text box. In my serial port class I use IPropertyChanged events and I succeeded in binding each incoming line to the textbox. But it's not satisfying just to see one line, the content of the textbox should be appended with each incoming line. I don't want to collect the strings in my serial port class and just send them all again with each new one. I tried and the result was very slow.

Next I tried to use the binding event TargetUpdated to use textbox.AppendText(incomingline) ...

```
<TextBox 
Name="textBoxIncoming" 
Text="{Binding Path=Incoming, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
DataContext="{Binding NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
IsReadOnly="True"
TargetUpdated="textBoxIncoming_TargetUpdated" 
... />`
```

The result was that each incoming line is displayed twice in the text box, the lines before are cleared.

Does anybody know, how to append text to a textbox with wpf binding ?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with a binding alone. Instead, create a List where you add all lines that you receive. Modify the Incoming property to return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, listOfReceivedStrings).

Comment: I think updating all the previous lines (let's say 100) together with the new incoming line is killing performance. New lines come in just about every millisecond. Now I tried a self-defined event LineReceived to append text to the textbox. But this brought me into crossthreading trouble. So I called wpf dispatcher BeginInvoke with every new line to append the line to the textbox. But this was similar slow.

Comment: Your solution is correct and basically the fastest you can get with TextBox. The text box is not made to contain extreme amounts of text. Next step for you would be to either try using a list (append an items) or do custom drawing code.